# How do I display this Error to users in Expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

How do i access the firstname, lastname, email and password.
example: how do i access if firstname exists and display the error to user like this firstname.msg.

```
[{"firstname":{"value":"","msg":"Firstname is required","param":"firstname","location":"body"},"lastname":{"value":"","msg":"Lastname must not contain number or symbol","param":"lastname","location":"body"},"email":{"value":"","msg":"Email is required","param":"email","location":"body"},"password":{"value":"","msg":"Password is required","param":"password","location":"body"}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your array to a variable, e.g. `results`. Then use `.map()` to iterate through each `results` object to check whether any of the `msg` properties are defined; if they are, save them to the new `errors` array. If no `msg` properties are defined, return `undefined`.

We then use `.filter()` to immediately remove any elements that are `undefined`, leaving the `errors` array only with string elements that equal the `msg` fields from `results` array.

Then finally, we are doing a check to see if the `errors` array has any elements in it, and if it does, return the first element (error message); in express it would be something like:

`if(errors.length > 0) return res.status(400).json(errors[0]);`.

This will always return the first error the function encounters.

```
const results = [{"firstname":{"value":"","msg":"Firstname is required","param":"firstname","location":"body"},"lastname":{"value":"","msg":"Lastname must not contain number or symbol","param":"lastname","location":"body"},"email":{"value":"","msg":"Email is required","param":"email","location":"body"},"password":{"value":"","msg":"Password is required","param":"password","location":"body"}}]

const errors = results
    .map(({ firstname, lastname, email, password }) => {
        if(firstname.msg) return firstname.msg;
        else if (lastname.msg) return lastname.msg;
        else if (email.msg) return email.msg;
        else if (password.msg) return password.msg;
        else return;
    })
    .filter(error => error);

if(errors.length > 0) return errors[0];
```